# Maintain a user's session state in an ASP.NET MVC app hosted on a web farm

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web-farm, asp.net-session

What is the best way to maintain a user's session state in an ASP.NET MVC app hosted on a web farm?

Out application currently uses the standard ASP.NET session on IIS 6.0 but we want to move the app to a web farm environment. 
I have read that we can use SQL Server session state for our application but I just want to know if anybody was using something else and why!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to [use the Velocity distributed cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/velocity/archive/2008/06/05/how-to-use-session-store-provider-microsoft-project-code-named-velocity.aspx).

Comment: Sadly it's not released yet, it is just in CTP. But I agree, when Velocity is released, it should become the premier way of distributing session state across Windows based HTTP servers.

Answer (score 1):

Storing session in SQL is still valid in MVC (as it was in WebForms):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

We're using it successfully across a few boxes for our MVC app, and have used it across quite a few boxes for older WebForms apps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing your sessions in memcache. Should be both fast and scalable. It does require some memory though.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in one of the StackOverflow podcasts: usually session state is very minimal - a few keys here and there - and works well to simply store this in a central database.